# Deleting lines containing duplicated strings

Tags: sed, duplicates, removeclass, uniq

I always appreciate your help.

I would like to delete lines containing duplicated strings in the second column.

test.txt

```
658 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_ecl_zlow_e 0.825692
659 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_byp_rd_data_e[31]  0.825692
660 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_byp_rd_data_e[63]  0.825692
661 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_ecl_zhigh_e    0.825692
665 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_byp_rd_data_e[62]  0.825692
666 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_ecl_zlow_e 0.825692
668 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_ecl_zhigh_e    0.825692
670 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_ecl_zhigh_e    0.825692
673 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_ecl_zlow_e 0.825692
675 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_ecl_zhigh_e    0.825692
677 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_ecl_zhigh_e    0.825692
678 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_byp_rd_data_e[27]  0.825692
679 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_byp_rd_data_e[27]  0.8120
.
.
.
```

output.txt

```
658 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_ecl_zlow_e 0.825692
659 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_byp_rd_data_e[31]  0.825692
660 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_byp_rd_data_e[63]  0.825692
661 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_ecl_zhigh_e    0.825692
665 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_byp_rd_data_e[62]  0.825692
678 invert_d2e_q_reg_0_/Qalu_byp_rd_data_e[27]  0.825692
.
.
.
```

I know sed can delete lines with predefined specific strings, but in my cases, I could not expect the strings are duplicated. Also, duplicated strings may be more than 1000.

I used “uniq” to do this job, but this does not work. 
uniq –u –f 4 test.txt
(-u prints unique lines.  –f skips the first 4 letters. )

Is there any way to do this with sed/awk/perl? Or please correct my uniq semantics.

Best,

Jaeyoung

Comment: `man sort` : look at the `-u` option. You'll need to specify a key, maybe `-k2` . Good luck.

Comment: `uniq` needs to operate on sorted input. So use `sort -k4 | uniq -u -f4`

Comment: `awk` with arrays should make this quick work.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'G;/^\S+\s+(\S+)\s+.*\n.*\1/!{P;s/\S+\s+(\S+)\s+.*/\1/;H};d' file
```

Test the second column against all unique values of that column stored in the hold space (HS) and if not present print the line and store its value in the HS.

Or use sort:

```
sort -suk2,2 file | sort -nk1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk would do this with one tool, but here is fairly straight forward way to do it with Bash associative arrays. Loop over the lines and pull out column three, if there is no associative array entry then echo the line out and set a value so it won't be printed any further.

```
unset col3 && declare -A col3 && IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in $(< test.txt); do 
 lncol3=$(echo "${a}" | tr '/' ' ' | awk '{print $3}')
 [[ -z "${col3["${lncol3}"]}" ]] && echo "${a}" && col3["${lncol3}"]=1
done
```

Comment: This is a useful technique to know, but `sort -uk2,2 test.txt|sort` gets the job done concisely.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).